# Retweet using CURL

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using twitter api for retweet. in my PHP file I am using CURL to send request like this

```
$ch = curl_init() or die('cURL not available');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $retweet_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $options);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$retweet_result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Its giving "Unable to authenticate error." . I have already authenticated user and created a session.

Comment: Are you sending username/password through curl and trying to use the session cookies?

Comment: Well thanks, its solved. basically I didnt gave twitter the "write" permission. Thanks btw.